# pythonの関数について

Tags: python, python3

```
def f(x):
    return x*2
    result = f(2)
    print(result)
```

と入力したところ、結果に４という数字が出てきません。どのようにすれば、よいでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

python は インデントでコードのまとまりを識別します。
f(x)関数定義と、関数の利用部分を同一レベルのインデントで定義しているため、f(x)を実行できなかったのではないかと思います。

以下のように、記述すれば良いのではないでしょうか?

```
def f(x):
  return x*2

result = f(2)
print(result)
```